# Update a row adding a relationed row in EF (many-to-many)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda

I have two entities: `Order` and `Item` and a many-to-many relationship between them. I have a method which receive the ItemId as parameter like this:

```
public void AddItems(int OrderId, int ItemId)
        {
            Item item = db.ItemSet.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == ItemId);
            Order order = db.OrderSet.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == OrderId);

            order.Items.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

There are a lot of rows in the ItemSet table, so the first query is a heavy one. Is there a way that I can add the item to the order without doing a query first on the "ItemSet" table? I mean, can I add the ItemId directly to the Order.Items or something like that?

Comment: If you want to be able to that, you need to model the Joining table in code! Then that way you can have finer grain control over the creation of these entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Item item = new Item { ID = ItemId };
        Order order = new Order { ID = OrderId };

        db.ItemSet.Attach(item);
        db.OrderSet.Attach(order);

        order.Items.Add(item);  

        db.SaveChanges();
```

Just be sure that you have this in your Order class:

```
    public Order()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }
```

So you don't get null pointer exception in `order.Items.Add(item);`

Answer (score 0):

So you can model the entities, so:

```
public DbSet<Item> ItemSet {get;set;}
public DbSet<Order> OrderSet {get;set;}
public DbSet<ItemOrder> ItemOrders {get;set;}

public class Item
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class ItemOrder
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ItemId {get;set;}

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
}
```

So in order to update:

```
    public void AddItems(int OrderId, int ItemId)
    {
        var itemExists = db.ItemOrders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderId == OrderId && x.ItemId == ItemId);

        if (itemExists != null) return;            

        db.ItemOrders.Add(new ItemOrder { OrderId = OrderId, ItemId = ItemId });

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Then you can query using the LINQ `.Join()` and is pretty straightforward.

Just for completeness sake the OP mentioned that the navigation properties have now disappeared. So if you know the `OrderId` then you can simple do:

```
var items = db.ItemOrders.GroupJoin(
                db.ItemSet,
                io => io.ItemId,
                i => i.Id,
                (itemOrder, items) => items)
              .ToList();
```

So to walk you through, `GroupJoin` asks for the `IQueryable`/`IEnumerable` of data you want to join against.

The second param is the field of the initial data set i.e. `ItemOrders` the set you want to join to.

The third parameter is the field of the set that is being joined in i.e. `ItemSet`.

The fouth parameter is basically a `Select` where you are presented with a `Func` signature of roughly `(ItemOrder itemInFirstSet, IEnumerable<Item> itemsThatAreJoined)`.

You can apply this same logic to the LINQ `Join` extension. But rather than `itemsThatAreJoined` it is `itemThatIsJoined`. So the distinction is `GroupJoin` will find multiple entities that match, `Join` will only find one.

This is no way a detailed explanation, more of an overview

Comment: But then I lose the navigation properties and can't do a foreach over `Order.Items`, for example.

Comment: You can, you just need to formulate a different query! Everything is possible

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Is this more efficient than do a query in the `ItemSet` table? If there are a lot of Items, there will be a lot more records in the `ItemOrders` table.

Comment: So in your example you are query to tables asking for particular entities, then you are adding an entity to the other and saving. In my example you are querying one table and asking for one entity and if it doesn't exist adding it. Because the table is using a composite key it will be index against that key so the lookup speed will be incredibly fast. So TL;DR: its two table queries vs one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. That table will have much more records. Take in mind that every time you add an item, a record is created.

Comment: you can try it yourself, use LinqPad to input over 2 million rows into your sql database with different Id combinations then do a select statement with a join...